# PYAUTOGUI IN FOR LOOP Python

Tags: pyautogui

I am trying to do a series of steps on each file in the directory. For each file, I want to copy the name of the file and then paste it at specified coordinates on the screen. The first three lines of code in the if statement seem to get ignored and all I see happen is the cursor move to the destination. None of the file names are getting copied to the clipboard and none are pasted. Please see error picture message attached. Any advice is much appreciated.
[pythonPicError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URAR1.png)

```
import pyautogui,os
directory = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\pdfs'
   for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        pyautogui.click() 
        pyautogui.press('f2') #select file name
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c') #copy file name
        pyautogui.moveTo(153,1054,duration=2)
        pyautogui.click() #click on destination
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','v') #paste file name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print something after each line of code, to see where exactly is the problem. But I guess

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c') #copy file name
```

ctrl+c is just killing your script :)

Just noticed:

```
pyautogui.click()
```

You didn't provide any coords for this click, so it's clicking just after you run the program in the place where your coursor is.

Comment: Thanks Dawid, I programmed coordinates and now it works.

Comment: Great. Comment if you have any more concerns. And upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed coordinates and now it works.

```
import pyautogui,os
directory = 'C:\\Users\\johna\\Desktop\\pdfs'

  x=226
  y=280
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        pyautogui.click(x,y)
        pyautogui.press('f2')
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','c')
        y=y+30
        pyautogui.moveTo(107,559,duration=2)
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','v')
```